# Updating three.js scene on window re-size

Tags: javascript, three.js

I used the following code for updating everything(camera, renderer etc) when I resize my window so that nothing distorts. It seems to work perfectly while manually resizing the window, however, when I maximize my window by just clicking the maximize icon, the images distort and the update loop breaks. Anyone familiar with this problem? thanks!

```
//resize
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight
  //update camera
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
})

const loop = () => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

loop();
```

Comment: ResizeObserver may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver .

Answer (score 1):

Try switch `aspect` with `updateProjecionMatrix`

When projection will be in relation to the new aspect ratio

```
camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

Comment: There actually is a mechanism here for expressing your gratitude for a helpful answer... Upvoting it! You never awarded any points or accepted his answer :(

Comment: @StijndeWitt
Sometimes people forget, sometimes they don't want, etc, like in life, thx for points :)